# Laptop shows 'not charging' after charging to 70% or more

Tags: windows, windows-10

Acer Aspire E5-571 I removed the battery and held the power button down for more than 15s, but it still didn't work. I thought it could be an hardware issue,so i took it to Acer service centre and they couldn't find anything wrong with it. They claimed it's an OS issue. They suggested i go back to windows 8.1 to get the problem fixed. Is there anything i can do to fix it? Or will i need to go back to windows 8.1 to fix it?

Comment: Software problem can by tested by live Linux. If on live Linux charging will work => it is OS problem, if not => it is hardware problem.

Comment: In order to stop the battery from wearing out, the battery is no longer charged when it has a certain level on "startup".

A 70% seems a bit low to me though.

Does the battery charge to 100% when the initial level is under 70% and charging is not interrupted?

Comment: @le_top yes it charges to 100% uninterrupted mostly when i put the laptop to sleep and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: Ok, it might be related a configuration.  I looked around and it may be available from "Mobility Center" after doing the Windows key + X.
You can check if your battery is still healthy using the [CPUID HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) - just get the ZIP (no install needed).  After running, the statistics give the initial capacity and the current capacity.  I guess that it is ok though.

Comment: Acer says they have a power management tool ePower with no user interface.